# Why is this javascript non-greedy regex matching nothing?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

Having the url and js regex below, I'd expect to catch the `f2fJsDFJ23`, but the non-greedy parts `.*?` and `\??` don't work as expected

What's the reasoning?

```js
let t = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/f2fJsDFJ23?autoplay=1'
let reg = /(?:embed\/)(.*?)(?:\??)/.exec(t)
document.write(`6>>> ${reg && reg.join(' | ')} <br/>`)

reg = /(?:embed\/)(.*)(?:\??)/.exec(t)
document.write(`6>>> ${reg && reg.join(' | ')} <br/>`)

reg = /(?:embed\/)(.*)(?:\?)/.exec(t)
document.write(`6>>> ${reg && reg.join(' | ')} <br/>`)

t = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/f2fJsDFJ23'
reg = /(?:embed\/)(.*?)(?:\??)/.exec(t)
document.write(`6>>> ${reg && reg.join(' | ')} <br/>`)

reg = /(?:embed\/)(.*)(?:\??)/.exec(t)
document.write(`6>>> ${reg && reg.join(' | ')} <br/>`)

reg = /(?:embed\/)(.*)(?:\?)/.exec(t)
document.write(`6>>> ${reg && reg.join(' | ')} <br/>`)
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/DgB5XU/1 the `?` is optional and there is nothing after it for the pattern to match so the non greedy will suffice with matching as least as possible. You could instead match either `?` or assert the end of the string.

Comment: Ok, I thought the `?` could also mean 0 matches, but it is not true, so instead I can use the OR operator, fabulous :) thanks a lot! (If you write the same answer in an answer I will close this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern the `(.*?)` part is non greedy giving up as least as possible. After that it will match an optional question mark. As the question mark is optional the the dot non greedy, the pattern will suffice matching embed/ only.

One option is to match either `?` or assert the end of the string `$` using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Note that you can omit the non capturing group around embed and the question mark.

```
embed\/(.*?)(?:\?|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U9aELU/1)

---

Another option is to use a negated character class matching any char except a `?` or a whitespace char:

```
embed\/([^?\s]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iCuCED/1)